# Help add ajax load more button

Tags: ajax, buttons, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to add the plugin "Easy Load More" to my theme (https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-load-more/).  You are supposed to wrap it in `<div id="ajax">` and then place `<?php load_more_button(); ?>` where you want the load more button to go.  I can't quite figure out the correct places to add this code (as you can see by my code below it is currently in the wrong places).  Below is a picture of how I want the load more button to look.

[image]

Here is my current `front-page.php`

```html
<?php
/*
 * Template Name:
 */

get_header();
get_template_part ('inc/carousel');

$the_query = new WP_Query( [
    'posts_per_page' => 14,
    'paged' => $paged
] );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { 
load_more_button();
?>
    <div id="ajax">
    <?php
    $i = 0;
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { $the_query->the_post();

        if ( $i % 7 === 0 ) { // Large post: on the first iteration and every 7th post after... ?>
        <article <?php post_class( 'col-md-12' ); ?>>
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('large-thumbnail'); ?>
            <h2><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <p class="post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            <?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
            <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
            <?php comments_popup_link ('No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?>
            </article><?php

        } else { // Small posts ?>

            <article <?php post_class( 'col-md-4' ); ?>>
                <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'medium-thumbnail' ); ?>
                <h2><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p class="post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                <?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
                <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                <?php comments_popup_link ('No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?>
            </article>
            <?php
        }
        $i++;
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
else {
    echo '<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>';
}
load_more_button();
get_footer();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your div wrapper is within your while loop, and split by your if clause.
This cannot work properly, since your loop will generate up to 14 divs with the id ajax.

Put the opening div tag after `if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {` and the closing after `wp_reset_postdata();` and you should be fine.

**Edit**

Are you sure, that you didn't miss any opening/closing php tags? e.g. load_more_button() is wrapped in php but you didn't close your php before.

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name:
 */

get_header();
get_template_part ('inc/carousel');

$the_query = new WP_Query( [
    'posts_per_page' => 14,
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged', 1)
] );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { ?>
    <div id="ajax">
    <?php
    $i = 0;
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { $the_query->the_post();

        if ( $i % 7 === 0 ) { // Large post: on the first iteration and every 7th post after... ?>
        <article <?php post_class( 'col-md-12' ); ?>>
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('large-thumbnail'); ?>
            <h2><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <p class="post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            <?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
            <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
            <?php comments_popup_link ('No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?>
            </article><?php

        } else { // Small posts ?>

            <article <?php post_class( 'col-md-4' ); ?>>
                <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'medium-thumbnail' ); ?>
                <h2><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p class="post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                <?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
                <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                <?php comments_popup_link ('No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?>
            </article>
            <?php
        }
        $i++;
    }?>
    </div>
    <?php if(get_query_var('paged') < $the_query->max_num_pages) {
       load_more_button();
    }
}
elseif (!get_query_var('paged') || get_query_var('paged') == '1') {
    echo '<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>';
}
wp_reset_postdata();
get_footer();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work.  It just creates an error because the page is blank.

Comment: Are you sure, that you didn't miss any opening/closing tags?

Comment: Now it moved all of the posts into once column.  Also when you press the load more button the same 14 posts just repeat themselves.  It doesn't call the next 14 posts.

Comment: Overlooked, that the paged is always set to 1 ;)

Comment: Do you have any suggestions to fix this?  I'm assuming this whole line is causing problems, but I don't know what to change it to? $the_query = new WP_Query( [
    'posts_per_page' => 14,
    'paged' => 1
] );

Comment: I tried changing it to 'paged' => $paged.  It seemed to work correctly.  It loaded the next 14 pots.  Is this the correct way to fix this?

Comment: So sorry for all the comments, I really appreciate your help! I noticed the load more button still appress even if all of the posts are loaded?  Is there a way to make it not appear if there are no more posts to show?

Comment: Yes, put the `load_the_button()` within your `if($the_query->have_posts())` wrapper. Adapted my answer.

Comment: I've updated my original question code.  Would it look like this?

Comment: No. Look at my answer. $paged must not be defined, better use  `get_query_var('paged', 1)`

Comment: Sorry did not see the code before.  The button still shows up even if there are no more posts to display.  It will disappear if you click it again, but I want it to not show up at all if there are no posts left.

Comment: I put an if clause around the button function that is checking current page vs. max_num_pages

Comment: hmmm the button is still showing up, oh well. Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it.